# Smooth curve fitting with 2D noise data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, smoothing, polynomials, bspline

I am having some trouble with smoothing position data in 2D.
I am having a sensor name GNSS which produces position data but GNSS is not accurate and it creates a lot of noise data even it was stable in one place. Here is the sample coordinate in one stable place

```
 [  60764.23449229 -100140.80706004]
 [  60764.84850004 -100141.01120966]
 [  60764.51855838 -100140.84762562]
 [  60763.35537281 -100141.33637028]
 [  60764.61105273 -100140.87806004]
 [  60763.75202809 -100140.93057157]
 [  60764.76660587 -100140.95289355]
 [  60764.24586045 -100140.80742297]
 [  60764.43356906 -100140.82418556]
 [  60763.28317904 -100141.50751476]
```

After that, I am trying to move it forward and get this sample coordinate

```
 [  60764.81948855 -100140.98207046]
 [  60764.92936364 -100140.96721928]
 [  60764.99700105 -100140.7012187 ]
 [  60765.19893018 -100140.42903945]
 [  60765.51303984 -100140.02736587]
 [  60765.80870981 -100139.61403094]
 [  60766.25182758 -100139.03935881]
 [  60766.74092995 -100138.3961776 ]
 [  60767.2590066  -100137.71298507]
 [  60767.74847494 -100137.01536319]
```

My goal here is trying to create a smooth movement from the start of GNSS in a stable place and moving forward and I have tried with Polynomial and B Spline to create a smooth curve but I still faced some problems with it ( I have just started with b spline curve, I might miss something ).

Is there any new solution or b spline solution to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [alpha-beta filte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_beta_filter)r to smooth the data

I've seen a few packages of it online, but the algorithm is just a few lines of code.

alpha-beta is a simple filter from the Kalman filter family, which generally used to solve these kind of problems.